# Conditionals Nested Loops in List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How to compress this whole loop into one single line. Is there any way?

```
aa = []  
for x in args:
   for y in args:
     if x == y:
       pass
     else:
       kk = x*y
       aa.append(kk)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested For Loops Using List Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633140/nested-for-loops-using-list-comprehension)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find cartesian product of lists filtering out the elements based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48791751/find-cartesian-product-of-lists-filtering-out-the-elements-based-on-condition)

Comment: Nested Loops are easy but conditions with it making it difficult@mkrieger1, @Gino Mempin

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product
aa = [x*y for x,y in product(args, args) if x != y]
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely nothing wrong with previous answer. A double loop also works and might be a little simpler to understand.

```
[x * y for x in args for y in args if x != y]
```

Comment: ``` total = 0 for x in args:
      total = total + x
  total2= 2*total ``` can this be compred in one line @Frank Yellin